# Creating calendar in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, eventkit

Let's consider the following line of code:

```
reminder.calendar = appDelegate!.eventStore!.defaultCalendarForNewReminders()
```

this denotes that I put reminder into the default device's calendar. How can I create my own calendar from code?

The reason I want to create my own one is that I want to have possibility to manage all reminders there.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Create a new `EKCalendar` instance for the specific type, assign a title and a source and save it to the database

```
let calendar = EKCalendar(for: .reminder, eventStore: eventStore)
calendar.title = "MyNewCalendar"
calendar.source = eventStore.defaultCalendarForNewReminders()?.source
do {
    try eventStore.saveCalendar(calendar, commit: true)
} catch { print(error) }
```

Retrieving the reminder calendar is a bit tricky

```
var myCalendar: EKCalendar?
let calendars = eventStore.calendars(for: .reminder)
if let filteredCalendar = calendars.first(where: {$0.title == "MyNewCalendar"}) {
    myCalendar = filteredCalendar
} else {
    print("count not find reminder calendar 'MyNewCalendar'")
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I got one more question if you don't mind. I try to access this calendar this way: reminder.calendar =
            appDelegate!.eventStore!.calendarWithIdentifier("MyNewCalendar")
and the result is: Reminder failed with error Optional("No calendar has been set.")

Comment: could you take a look if you don't mind? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31456504/deleting-reminders-from-calendar-in-swift

Comment: Apple now recommends to add "where:" key before trailing closures so the code would change like :  if let filteredCalendar = calendars.first(where: {$0.title == "MyNewCalendar"}) {
    myCalendar = filteredCalendar
}