# Deleting reminders from calendar in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, eventkit

I use the following function to retrieve my calendar:

```
func retrieveCalendar() -> EKCalendar? {

    appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate
        as? AppDelegate

    var myCalendar:  EKCalendar?
    let calendars = appDelegate!.eventStore!.calendarsForEntityType(EKEntityTypeReminder) as! [EKCalendar]
    let filteredCalendars = calendars.filter {$0.title == "MedicalCalendar"}
    if filteredCalendars.isEmpty {
        println("could not find reminder calendar 'MedicalCalendar'")
        return nil
    } else {
        myCalendar = filteredCalendars[0]
        return myCalendar!
    }

}
```

However, anytime I add new events to the calendar I'd like to check if they already exist there. I figured out that the easiest approach would be to delete all reminders and load new ones again. I tried:

```
self.retrieveCalendar()?.reset()
```

But it does not work. How can I remove reminders from calendar?(either one at a time or all of them at once)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To check reminders you have to call the method `fetchRemindersMatchingPredicate()` in conjunction with `predicateForRemindersInCalendars` or `predicateForIncompleteRemindersWithDueDateStarting:ending:calendars:` or `predicateForCompletedRemindersWithCompletionDateStarting:ending:calendars:`

For example if you want to delete all expired reminders in the past until now, use something like this

- assumed properties:

  ```
  var calendar : EKCalendar // current calendar
  let eventStore : EKEventStore // current event store
  ```
- code

  ```
  func removeExpiredReminders() {

       let pastPredicate = eventStore.predicateForIncompleteRemindersWithDueDateStarting(nil, ending:NSDate(), calendars:[calendar])

      eventStore.fetchRemindersMatchingPredicate(pastPredicate) { foundReminders in

          let remindersToDelete = !foundReminders.isEmpty
          for reminder in foundReminders  as! [EKReminder] {
              self.eventStore.removeReminder(reminder, commit: false, error: nil)
          }
          if remindersToDelete {
              self.eventStore.commit(nil)
          }
      }
  }
  ```

in the loop you can check for further conditions

Comment: Thanks, I will check it later on and get back to you! What if I want to remove all reminders, neither only expired nor any specific ones?

Comment: use `predicateForRemindersInCalendars`, that predicate considers all reminders, see the programming guide: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/EventKitProgGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html